# Como fazer um consulta passando parametros com o spring boot e redis usando JPARepository?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, redis

Tenho o modelo:

```
@Data
@RedisHash("customer")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @NotNull
    private String firstName;
   ...
```

Tenho a seguinte interface:

```
@EnableRedisRepositories
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, String> {

   Optional<Customer>  findByFirstName(String firstName);
}
```

O Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class CustomerService {
    private final CustomerRepository repository;

    public CustomerService(CustomerRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

   ...


      public Optional<Customer> retrieveCustomersByName(String name) {
            return repository.findByFirstName(name);
        }
}
```

E o seguinte restcontroller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customers")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

 ....

    @GetMapping("/{firstName}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getCustomers(@PathVariable String firstName) {
        Optional<?> customer = customerService.retrieveCustomersByName(firstName);
        if (!customer.isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().build();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(customer);
    }


}
```

> Todos os metodos de crud estão ok!

Porem quando faço a consulta pelo postman ele não retorna nenhum resultado do redis. O que devo fazer?

url usada no postman:

http://localhost:9000/api/customers/paulo

arquivo application.yml:

```
server:
  port: 9000
  servlet:
    contextPath: /api
```

Comment: Desculpa a ignorancia, mas eu não vi "api" mapeado em nenhum lugar no seu código, é necessário que esteja na url?

Comment: @Scarabelo Que nada, a "api" esta mapeado no arquivo application.properties, mas no meu caso, esta mapeado no arquivo application.yml , que dá no mesmo.Vou colocar no código acima –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na classe de modelo acrescente a anotação **@Indexed**
do pacote **org.springframework.data.redis.core.index.Indexed;**

```
@Data
@RedisHash("customer")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @NotNull
    @Indexed
    private String firstName;
   ...
```